# Resetting the sort order of SSMS's Object Explorer Details

Tags: sql-server, ssms

This has bugged me for years and after numerous but short searches over the last decade I have never found an answer so can only assume it must be an obvious thing that no-one else struggles with but here goes...

How do I change the sort order in the SSMS Object Explorer Details tab back to the default sort order?  (i.e. folders at the top and then sorted by Schema and then by Object Name)

When I click on a column to sort by that column I typically then wish to return to the default sort order but for the life of me I've never worked out how to do it (after about 15 years of using SSMS!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right click a column header and choose "Reset View"
2. Click the refresh button at the top of the pane

Comment: Well, what can I say other than thanks and it works!  I have hit that reset view option so many times but must never have then hit the refresh button as well.  Looks like it does indeed need to be this sequence of clicks; bizarre!  #WhoKnew

Comment: Yeah, I'd have expected reset view to just do it off the bat. Maybe file a bug with MS :)

Comment: To be honest now that I know, and even though its counter-intuitive, I kinda like it - feels like a secret easter egg...  or perhaps it was just me who was in the dark :)